# How to use pp (PAR Packer) in a batch script?

Tags: batch-file, perl-packager

I am using PAR Packer to create executables from a series of Perl scripts. I can create the executable using the command:

```bash
pp perl_script1.pl -o test1.exe
```

When I place all the `pp` commands into a batch script and execute it in `cmd.exe`, the batch script exits after running the first line.

```bash
pp perl_script1.pl -o test1.exe
pp perl_script2.pl -o test2.exe
pp perl_script3.pl -o test3.exe
pp perl_script4.pl -o test4.exe
```

How can I add multiple `pp` commands to a single batch script, and launch it to create all the executables at once?

Comment: use `call pp...`

Comment: @Magoo What is the logic behind it?

Comment: `pp` appears to ba a batch file. When a batch file is executed from a batch file, execution is simply passed to the second batch. When the second batch ends, so does the process. `call` causes the target executable to be executed and when it ends, returns execution to the statement following the `call`.

Comment: @Magoo Perhaps you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pp` appears to be a batch file.

When a batch file is executed from a batch file, execution is simply passed to the second batch.

When the second batch ends, so does the process.

`call` causes the target executable to be executed and when it ends, returns execution to the statement following the `call`

Comment: if `pp` return with an error, will the rest of the command be executed?

Comment: Yes, unless you follow the `call pp...` line with `if errorlevel 1 goto somelocation` where `somelocation` is a label in the file, logically reporting the error. You could also follow `call pp ...` with `if errorlevel 1 set "errormessage=sometext %errorlevel%"&goto reporterror` where reporterror` is a label executing `echo error %errorlessage%` - and the actual errorlevel returned from `pp` will be reported. Just change `sometext` to indicate which step failed.